# Commutative Diagrams in R-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

**Definitions:**
$1)$ *$R$-Algebra*: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$. An $R$-Algebra is a ring $A$ with $1\neq 0$ together with a ring homomorphism $f:R\rightarrow A$ such that $f(1_{R})=1_{A}$.
$2)$ *$R$-Algebra Homomorphism*: Let $A$ and $B$ be two $R$-Algebras. An $R$-Algebra Homomorphism is a ring homomorphism $\varphi:A\rightarrow B$ mapping $1_{A}$ to $1_{B}$ such that $\varphi (r.a)=r.\varphi (a)$ $\forall r\in R$ and $a\in A$.

**My Question:**
Let the functions associated with $A$ and $B$ $R$-Algebras be $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ respectively. Then, does the diagram below commutes i.e. $\varphi \omicron f_{1}= f_{2}?$ 
$\require{AMScd}$
 \begin{CD} R&\xrightarrow{f_{1}} &A\\ & f_{2}\searrow &\downarrow{\varphi}\\& &B\end{CD}

My intuition says it is not necessary. But I have no proof or counterexample to prove it. Moreover, I want to know whether by imposing some conditions on $f_{1}$, $\varphi$ and $f_{2}$, can we make the above diagram commutative?

Comment: Please edit my question to insert a proper commutative diagram. Thanks. :)

Comment: I don't thing commutative diagrams are possible here.

Comment: Maybe just type it somewhere and post the link.

Comment: @ThorWittich I don't know how to draw commutative diagrams in Latex. I did a google search but couldn't find much to do it in a proper way. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r \in R, a \in A$ we have by definition $r.a = f_1(r) a$ and for $b \in B$ we have $r.b = f_2(r) b$. Now $$\varphi(f_1(r)) = \varphi(r . 1_A) = r. \varphi(1_A) = f_2(r) 1_B = f_2(r).$$

Comment: The definition $r.a=f_{1}(r)a$ that you have used is used for defining $A$ $R$-algebra over $R$- module. It's not included in the definition $1$. Please rectify your answer.

Comment: @Kumar I don't really understand your comment. How do you define $r.a$ in an $R$-algebra which is, in your definition, defined by a morphism $R \to A$, where $A$ is a commutative ring with unity. I mean, you also have a definition for $R$-algebra homomorphism, which includes the notation $r.a$. How is this defined in your case?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understood my definition properly. These are taken from Dummit and foote $(3^{ed})$. I think your answer is good enough. Thanks.